# GWT devmode netbeans - error

Tags: java, css, jakarta-ee, gwt

After hours of searching solution i need to ask you.
maybe this question is duplicate but please how i can fix this:

in netbeans when i run the project  as GWT Dev. mode (hosted mode) The browser alerts following (when i select menu item, it wont load JInternalFrame) (when i deploy it into glassfish it works perfectly):

```
Uncaught exception escaped : java.lang.AssertionError
The style name '-mozOpacity' should be in camelCase format
See the Development console log for details.
Register a GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(..) for custom uncaught exception handling.
```

when deploying it fork perfectly. but build and deploy takes 15 minutes. So  i really need to fix this. SmartGWT and GWT sdk is latest version. we dont used setAttribute or -mozOpacity in our code. so this is something included in GWT.

> 00:00:26,149 [ERROR] Uncaught exception escaped
>   java.lang.AssertionError: The style name '-mozOpacity' should be in
>   camelCase format  at
>   com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style$.assertCamelCase$(Style.java:2154)    at
>   com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style$.setProperty$(Style.java:2021)    at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.setStyleAttribute(DOM.java:1240)   at
>   org.gwm.client.impl.OutlinePanel.initUI(OutlinePanel.java:33)     at
>   org.gwm.client.impl.OutlinePanel.(OutlinePanel.java:25)     at
>   org.gwm.client.impl.DefaultGFrame.initializeFrame(DefaultGFrame.java:188)
>     at org.gwm.client.impl.DefaultGFrame.(DefaultGFrame.java:174)
>     at
>   org.gwm.client.impl.DefaultGInternalFrame.(DefaultGInternalFrame.java:57)
>     at
>   org.gwm.client.impl.DefaultGInternalFrame.(DefaultGInternalFrame.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gwm.client.impl.DefaultGInternalFrame.(DefaultGInternalFrame.java:47)
>     at
>   com.softtechEU.gwtDataModule.iframes.JInternalFrame.(JInternalFrame.java:33)
>     at
>   com.softtechEU.client.warehouse.ArticleListFrame.(ArticleListFrame.java:23)
>     at com.softtechEU.client.MenuControl$6.execute(MenuControl.java:151)
>     at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.MenuBar$1.execute(MenuBar.java:900)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl$Task$.executeScheduled$(SchedulerImpl.java:50)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.runScheduledTasks(SchedulerImpl.java:180)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl.flushFinallyCommands(SchedulerImpl.java:279)
>     at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.exit(Impl.java:266)     at
>   com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:257)    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Thank youuu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not issue related to GWT libs. Either you have a piece of code that is setting a css property with a "dash" or the SmartGWT lib has such a piece of code. You can see a similar reported issue on GWT issue list - https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5152

The solution is to avoid such css property usage in GWT code. Use non dash property name in the GWT code.

Comment: thank you,, i will check the libs that developed other team members